# Redirect dynamic top level domains to www subdomains with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get it so that any non-subdomained top level URL within my Nginx gets rewritten to a subdomain of www.

I cannot do the normal trick of using a normal server name since I have about 20 top level domains pointing to this server. Yes I could write a function out for each one, though I can feel my soul start to fade by just saying it.

I cannot create blanket rules since I use the subdomains of these top level domains in other configurations within the Nginx server.

So essentially I need to pickout `example.com`/`example.co.uk`/`example.eu`/`example.ly` all the same and redirect them to their www subdomain while ensuring I only pick them if they are not subdomains.

I go thus far:

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name ~^([^\.].*)\.(com|co.uk|eu|ly)$;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

However, it keeps adding the `www` twice, making the URL `www.www.example.com` and I have no clue why.

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: How are you subdomains handled in your configuration ? Are you using one regex for them too ?

Comment: @XavierLucas I have taken all other servers out of my configuration currently to test this on its own

Comment: So that's the issue because your regex matches also www.example.com. You need to put the subdomains server block(s) in your configuration and make sure, if using a regex, that it is declared before the one in your post (regexs are tested sequentially).

Comment: @XavierLucas so the server name regex can match www if I don't have a www server?

Comment: Of course, nothing prevents it : `([^\.].*)` matches also `www.example` because of the `.*` part.

Comment: @XavierLucas ok kool thanks I will try that tomorrow, it is late now, I always had the thought that if the server name regex don't match it wouldn't run that block

Comment: @XavierLucas though in that group it is omitting `.` using the `^` which means that www. shouldn't match since it would mean three segments but the regex only matches two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, either you declare your subdomains server blocks and make sure if you are using a regex too that it's preceding the server block redirecting to www (regex are tested sequentially), or you refine your regex so it would be `^[^.]+\.(com|co.uk|eu|ly)$`.

**Edit** : As you are only letting one server block in your configuration, everything will go throw this unique server block anyway, so you need at least to add :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

So headers not matching the regex will fallback into this default server block and connections will be closed by nginx. Then add your subdomain server blocks back.

Comment: That also redircts to www.www. I will try and add a www server block tomorrow and see if that helps

Comment: No it doesn't, test it with curl (browsers cache response headers).

Comment: Ok I will, I have cleared the cache of both chrome, IE, Opera, FF and Safari but I will try with curl

Comment: Does wget cache, cos I just tried it on there for the first time and I see it doing 3 redirects, one to www. then another again

Comment: Hum did you let one default server block for non-matching Host headers ? Add `server { listen 80 default_server; }` to your current configuration so it fallbacks in a different server block. Remove the default_server directive in the block containing the regex.

Answer (score 0):

As an advancement on the accepted I changed my config to be more like:

```
server {
    server_name ~^www\.[^.]+\.(com|co.uk|eu|ly)$;
    return 444;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name ~^[^.]+\.(com|co.uk|eu|ly)$;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

So now when the latter sever redirects it will instantly be picked up by the prior server but the first server will not pickup what the second should.

I have tested this a couple of times and it seems to work well.